# CSS deve ser Shorthand ou Longhand

Tags: css, css3

Afina qual é a prática correta, usar o CSS com ***Shorthand*** ou ***Longhand***? Procurei, mas não achei uma reposta definitiva...

Quando declaramos a classe com *Shorthand* estamos dizendo que todos os outros valores devem ser setados como `initial`. Vou demonstrar apenas algumas situações que ilustram meu interesse e dúvida.

> A value which is not specified is set to its `initial` value. *Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties

Logo quando declaramos nossa cor de BG assim:

```
div { 
     background: red;
}
```

Na verdade estamos dizendo, ou pelo menos é assim que o Browser está lendo, isso:

```
div { 
    background-image: initial; 
    background-position-x: initial; 
    background-position-y: initial; 
    background-size: initial; 
    background-repeat-x: initial; 
    background-repeat-y: initial; 
    background-attachment: initial; 
    background-origin: initial; 
    background-clip: initial; 
    background-color: red; /* mas eu só queria o bg :) */
}
```

- Isso é bom para performance?
- É melhor declara todos os valores individualmente ou *deixar o Browser processar todos os valores que não estamos declarando*?

---

**Possíveis problemas com o Shorthand** (mais um exemplo com background)

Exemplo de problema simples de ***shorthand*** com `background` fazendo *override* nas classes definidas pelo componente default.

```
.base-class { 
    height: 50px; 
    width: 100%;
    background-position: 0 0; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
} 
.base-class--modifier { 
    background: radial-gradient(...) 
}

<div class="base-class base-class--modifier"></div>
```

Deveria ser usado `background-image: radial-gradient(...)`

Hoje como o ***Emmet*** e softwares que já tem *autocomplit* de quase tudo ainda vale a pena escrever CSS com atalhos? Ou é melhor ser mais conciso nas declarações dos estilos?

***Existe alguma boa prática?*** *Considerando performance, manutenibilidade, leiturabilidade, etc*

Links de referência:

- https://csswizardry.com/2016/12/css-shorthand-syntax-considered-an-anti-pattern/
- https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-shorthand-longhand-notations/

Comment: Por que precisa existir uma "prática correta"? O CSS oferece ambas as opções, para serem usadas conforme for mais conveniente em cada caso.

Comment: @bfavaretto estou perguntando pq por exemplo no guia de estilo da Google eles encorajam o uso do Shorthand, já a Mozilla parece preferir o Longhand. Se for para usar em um site *single page* é melhor o CSS ***short*** ou*** long***, ou se for para uma aplicação web com um monte de pessoa mexendo no projeto é melhor ***short*** ou ***long***? Muitas vezes não depende só de nós a escolha. Por isso perguntei se teria alguma prática mais correta no mundo do desenvolvimento ou se cada um que põem a mão faz do jeito que quer...

Comment: Não é "cada um faz como quer", tem que ter critério. Estou pensando numa possível resposta pra você. Achei referência do Google sobre shorthand, mas não essa da Mozilla que você diz que prefere longhand. Tem um link?

Comment: @bfavaretto Link direto no site da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties (atenção em *Tricky edge cases*). Guia de CSS: http://codeguide.co/#css-shorthand . Eu gostaria de seguir um padrão, mas parece que não tem... Em projetos grandes complica pra todo mundo. Por isso estava buscando uma prática mais consistente. Mas talvez o "gosto pessoal" seja a resposta atual apesar de ainda não ser a melhor solução.

Comment: É mais bom-senso que gosto pessoal. Infelizmente ando sem tempo para escrever uma resposta mais elaborada. Mas o princípio básico é ser econômico. Eu seguiria o que o Google diz, tomando cuidado com os edge cases como os apontados no site da Mozilla. Aliás não acho que ali eles tomem partido por sempre usar longhand, apenas apontam os casos em que ser econômico pode causar problemas.

Comment: Pelo que li do primeiro link na questão: você deve usar o _short hand_ para poupar tempo e energia (talvez até mesmo ganhar legibilidade). O pessoal do Mozilla prefere então o _long hand_ quando precisam de um controle mais granular das propriedades. Controle mais grosso seria com _short hand_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Afina qual é a prática correta, usar o CSS com Shorthand ou Longhand?

Voce respondeu com o seu link: https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/css-shorthand-longhand-notations/long-vs-short-notations.jpg so precisa olhar "When to use"

> Isso é bom para performance?

Performance no css esta relacionada com uso de id, tag e Universal.

```
#main-navigation {   }      /* ID (O mais Rapido) */
body.home #page-wrap {   }  /* ID */
.main-navigation {   }      /* Class */
ul li a.current {   }       /* Class *
ul {   }                    /* Tag */
ul li a {  }                /* Tag */
* {   }                     /* Universal (O mais lento) */
#content [title='home']     /* Universal */
```

Voce pode confirir nesse site sobre perfomance https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

> Existe alguma boa prática?

Reuso da css é uma boa pratica, mas a performance é 10 milisegundos a mais(apenas uma ideia de tempo), css propria fazendo uso de Id nao é reutilizavel(a menos que seja vc que esta reutilizando) mas é mais rapido e por  nao ser reutilizavel seria uma ma pratica.

Uma boa pratica em geral, por css ser tao leve e cada empresa ou designer ter o seu proprio estilo de organizacao que chega a ser impossivel gerar um design pattern a ser seguido por todos, css roda em menos de 0.1 segundo(bem menos estou colocando por alto), esse tempo pode "aumentar" nao muita coisa quando se faz o uso de pseudo-class.

(EDITADO) "Evitar usar o css dentro do html, pq é dificil de dar manuteçao."

E por ultimo, terminou o css gere o minify porque o "maior problema" é para carregar o arquivo e nao a sua leitura.

*Desculpe a falta de ascentos meu teclado no momento nao possue tais teclas(teclado turco)

Comment: Hudson obrigado pela resposta. Ao meu ver uma imagem com "Pors e Contras" é uma resposta que fica encima do muro, não acho que ela seja uma resposta unanime ou que estabeleça algum critério sólido para um time. Já sobre os IDs o mais rápido não são eles, na verdade são os estilos "in-line", seguem palavras do Google sobre isso. *"talvez seja preciso dividir o CSS em duas partes: uma parte in-line, responsável por configurar a parte do conteúdo acima da dobra, e a parte que pode ser adiada"* https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent?csw=1" []´s

Comment: Minha dúvida sobre a performance na verdade está ligada ao que quando vc fala `background:red` vc deixa por conta do Browser "descobrir" que as outras declarações do background estão vazias. E quando vc diz `background-color:red` vc poupa processamento do browser, pois ele não fica esperando receber outros valores do `background` Por isso o questionamento sobre Long ou Short, principalmente em estilos que podem ter muitas variáveis como o BG  por exemplo.

Comment: sobre in-line eu citei aqui: "E por ultimo, terminou o css gere o minify porque o "maior problema" é para carregar o arquivo e nao a sua leitura.", Id carregam mais rapido do que class isso pode ser provado aqui http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/csscreate.php?n=1000&sel=%23id&body=background%3A+%23CFD&ne=1000

Comment: Hudson o Estilo "inline" é quando é direto na Tag e não Minificado, tipo `<div style="background-color:red;">`

Comment: Voce pode gerar dividir o css em duas partes onde a primeira vai carregar "big load" e a segunda parte o "small load" colocar css junto com html é a pior pratica possivel que voce pode fazer.

Comment: Cara isso depende muito, existem vária bibliotecas onde cada componente tem seu HTML/CSS/JS tudo junto em um arquivo só *(single file web component)*, isso pode depender muito do tipo e da faze do projeto. O Vue mesmo usa bastante essa metodologia no desenvolvimento. Depois da uma olhada se te interessar sobre shadow dom e cssom

Comment: vou dar uma olhada sim.