# Animação que revela elemento da esquerda para a direita

Tags: html, scss

Tenho um `<mat-divider></mat-divider>` e preciso fazer com que ele seja revelado da esquerda para a direita, como se fosse uma barra de progresso sendo preenchida

Alguém tem algum exemplo para me apresentar? Só consegui encontrar com javascript

@Edit:

Adicionando exemplo:

```css
@-moz-keyframes roll {
 0% { width:0; }
  100% { width:100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll {
 0% { width:0; }
  100% { width:100%; }
}

.multi-steps > li.is-active:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
    content: counter(stepNum);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after {
    background-color: #ededed;
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:before {
    content: counter(stepNum);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:after {
    background-color: #ededed;
  }
  
  .multi-steps {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .multi-steps > li {
    counter-increment: stepNum;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    color: #a1c642;
    z-index:99!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active {
    color: #a1c642!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista {
    color: darkorange!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li:before {
    content: '\f00c';
    content: '\2713;';
    content: '\10003';
    content: '\10004';
    content: '\2713';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a1c642;
    border-radius: 50%;

  }
  .multi-steps > li:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a1c642;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
  }


  .multi-steps > li:last-child:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: darkorange;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #a1c642;;
    
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
    color: #808080;
    
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-color: #ededed;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li {
    color: #808080;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:before {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-color: #ededed;
  }
```

```html
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
                                      <li>Pedido recebido</li>
                                      <li [class.is-active]="pedido.status == 'book_product' && pedido.id_Nota_fiscal == null">Pagamento aprovado</li>
                                      <li [class.is-active-acao-lojista]="pedido.status == 'payment_received' && pedido.id_Nota_fiscal == null">Faturar pedido</li>
                                      <li [class.is-active-acao-lojista]="pedido.status == 'payment_received' && pedido.id_Nota_fiscal !== null">Enviar dados rastreio</li>
                                      <li>Confirmar entrega</li>
                                    </ul>
```

Eu preciso aplicar a animação roll no ultimo elemento li:after que possui o `background-color #a1c642`

Tentei:

```
  .multi-steps > li:after:last-child{
      animation-name: roll;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
```

mas nada acontece

Comment: Olha se é isso que vc precisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262900/como-fazer-uma-barra-de-progresso-que-v%C3%A1-de-0-a-100-somente-com-css/334153#334153

Comment: Adicionei um edit para mostrar mais informações

Comment: Veja o **EDIT** que fiz na resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu CSS está com um problema na construção dessa classe.

Isso:

```
.multi-steps > li:after:last-child
```

Deveria ser isso:

```
.multi-steps > li:last-child:after
```

Repare na posição do `::after`

Outro problema é a lógica do que vc quer fazer, repare que se vc vai animar o `::after` do `last-child` ele vai animar para fora do "componente"... não sei se é isso que vc quer.

---

**EDIT**

Repare que no CSS do seu comentário vc escreveu errado! Na última linha vc acabou por zerar todos os valores da sua animação quando escrever

```
animation: forwards !important;
```

Dessa forma vc deixa tudo "zerado" e o único parâmetro da animação fica sendo o `forwards` ai a animação não funciona!

O correto seria:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recomendo essa leitura: [CSS deve ser Shorthand ou Longhand](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271393/css-deve-ser-shorthand-ou-longhand)

Segue o código da imagem acima, acredito que com ele vc consiga chegar no resultado que espera.

```css
@-moz-keyframes roll {
  0% { width:0; }
  100% { width:100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  0% { width:0; }
  100% { width:100%; }
}

.multi-steps > li.is-active:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
    content: counter(stepNum);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after {
    background-color: #ededed;
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:before {
    content: counter(stepNum);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:after {
    background-color: #ededed;
  }
  
  .multi-steps {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .multi-steps > li {
    counter-increment: stepNum;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    color: #a1c642;
    z-index:99!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active {
    color: #a1c642!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista {
    color: darkorange!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li:before {
    content: '\f00c';
    content: '\2713;';
    content: '\10003';
    content: '\10004';
    content: '\2713';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a1c642;
    border-radius: 50%;

  }
  .multi-steps > li:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a1c642;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
  }


  .multi-steps > li:last-child:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: darkorange;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #a1c642;;
    
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
    color: #808080;
    
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-color: #ededed;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li {
    color: #808080;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:before {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-color: #ededed;
  }
  
  .multi-steps > li:after{ 
  width: 0!important; 
  animation-name: roll !important; 
  animation-timing-function: linear !important; 
  animation-duration:5s !important; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards !important; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
  <li>Pedido recebido</li>
  <li [class.is-active]="pedido.status == 'book_product' && pedido.id_Nota_fiscal == null">Pagamento aprovado</li>
  <li [class.is-active-acao-lojista]="pedido.status == 'payment_received' && pedido.id_Nota_fiscal == null">Faturar pedido</li>
  <li [class.is-active-acao-lojista]="pedido.status == 'payment_received' && pedido.id_Nota_fiscal !== null">Enviar dados rastreio</li>
  <li>Confirmar entrega</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Não é muito bem o que eu preciso :/ , eu acho que eu preciso aplicar no angular uma classe preencheStatus que seria algo tipo:   .preencheStatus{
    .multi-steps > li:after{
        width: 0!important;
        animation-timing-function: linear!important;
        animation-name: roll!important;
        animation-duration:5s!important;  
        animation: forwards!important;
    }
  }

Comment: Porém dessa forma nao está aplicando a animação no li

Comment: @RenatoVeronese mas esse seu CSS ai está errado, vc vao colocando todos os parâmetros da animação e depois na última linha vc colocou `animation: forwards!important;` escrever assim elimina todos os outros valores que vc colocou na animação... o certo seria escrever `animation-fill-mode: forwards !important; `. Repare que eu editei o CSS da minha resposta e deixei os detalhes lá.